# Delete the begin and the end with regex

Tags: regex

Here is my phrase : "Begin xxxxxxxxx The End"

With

> re(r'Begin\s*(.*)')

i can delete the word "Begin"

But in the same time how to delete "The End"

Comment: `/(^Begin\s?|\s?The\sEnd$)/ig` or something of the sort? (Unsure about what version of regex you're using, however; if anyone's in the know can you update tags please?)

Comment: i try to reproduce and complete this example (http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#using-selectors-with-regular-expressions)

Comment: what flavor of regex are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one,

```
(?i)(^Begin|The\sEnd$)
```

just remove `(?i)` if you want case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Just add more after your `.*`.  A question mark will minimize the match so you don't pick up the surrounding spaces.

```
r'Begin\s*(.*?)\s*The End'
```

Note that you're not actually deleting anything; you're returning the text in the middle.